# Inserting into a table only when a record doesn't exist

Tags: sql-server

```
Insert into t1(col1,col2,col3)    
select   
t2.col1,
t2.col2,
t3.col2

from 
table2 t2 left outer join
table3 t3     
on t2.col1=t3.col1
```

This is the basics of my code. How do I check if the data getting inserted, already exists or not?

Comment: By using `LEFT JOIN`, all the data from `table2` get inserted into `t1`..

Comment: In the absence of any constraints, everything returned by the `SELECT` would be inserted.  What is your exact question?

Comment: Use IF EXISTS()  FUNCTION

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 if(not exists (select col1 from t1 where col1 in(select   
t2.col1 
from 
table2 t2 left outer join
table3 t3     
on t2.col1=t3.col1)))

   Begin
Insert into t1(col1,col2,col3)    
select   
t2.col1,
t2.col2,
t3.col2

from 
table2 t2 left outer join
table3 t3     
on t2.col1=t3.col1
   end
```

ps here its checking only col1 data you can add col2 and col3 as well

Answer (score 0):

Using [SQL EXISTS](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_exists.asp) Operator

```
 INSERT  INTO t1
        ( col1 ,
          col2 ,
          col3
        )
        SELECT  t2.col1 ,
                t2.col2 ,
                t3.col2
        FROM    table2 t2
                LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.col1 = t3.col1
        WHERE   NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                             FROM   T1
                             WHERE  t1.col1 = t2.col1
                                    AND t1.col2 = t2.col2
                                    AND t1.col3 = t3.col2 )
```